# Overload unary operator as binary operator

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

In Python, is it possible to override a unary operator (such as `~`) so that it acts as a binary one?

The result would be that `a ~ b` would become a meaningful expression.

Comment: Changing a unary operator to a binary one isn't simply overloading, it's changing the syntax of the language.

Comment: No, you can't change the basic grammar of the language. Operator overloading only allows you to override the function that's called, but parsing is indepedent of the values.

Comment: What do you want to do with that?